# Array/classes Constant expression contains invalid operations

Tags: php, arrays

I can't understand why this doesn't work:

```
class TestOne
{

    public static $TEST = array(
        "test" => array( "name" => TestTwo::$TEST2[ "test" ] ) // error line
)}

class TestTwo
{
    public static $TEST2 = array(
        "test" => "result"
    );
}
```

this gives me the error:

> Constant expression contains invalid operations

I would like `TestOne::$TEST[ "test" ][ "name" ]` to contain "result"

Comment: PHP version?  Used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Constant scalars expressions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs) cannot reference variables (as they are not constant).

You'll have to initialize the property some other way (e.g. through a static accessor) or avoid public static properties altogether.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can not use other variables while defining the variables of a class.

To give you a simple example,

```
$test = "result";

class TestOne {
    public static $TEST = $test;
}
```

would've given you the same error because you can not refer to other variables while defining them in a class. Only way you can do it is:

```
class TestOne
{

    public static $TEST = array(
        "test" => array(
            "name" => "result"
        )
    );
}

class TestTwo
{
    public static $TEST2 = array(
        "test" => "result"
    );
}
```